# space between folder name error in command prompt

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to create a new Yii app from command prompt.

**c:\Users\my foldername\wamp\yiifrmaework> yiic webapp c:\Users\my foldername\wamp\www\yiifilename**

This throws an error that unsupported VCS specified. I found the reason for the error from the manual that I used space between the folder(my foldername). Is there any way i can solve this problem ? how to avoid the space between the bolder name without changing the name name itself?

-any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around your path...

```
yiic webapp "c:\Users\my foldername\wamp\www\yiifilename"
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! just that simple solution :) i was ignorant. thanks again